# How do I set the default number of sheets in new OO Calc files?

Tags: openoffice-calc

In Microsoft Excel and OpenOffice.org, new spreadsheet files always come with three sheets by default (i.e. Sheet 1, Sheet 2, Sheet 3).

How to I change the default to just one sheet in OpenOffice.org??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of templates.

1. Open a blank workbook
2. Remove the worksheets as required
3. File > Templates > Save

   - *Templates* dialog will popup
4. Give your template a name (Note the category folder you are in)
5. Click **OK**

You've now saved a version of a workbook [to use as a template](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=56586). All you need do is [set it up to open as the default](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Setting_a_default_template).

1. File > Templates > Organize

   - *Template Management* dialog window will appear
2. In the left pane, navigate to where you save the template previously created
3. Click **Commands**
4. Select **Save As Default Template**
5. Click **Close**

Now, the next time you fire up Calc, the template you created will open up ready for you to use instead of the previous default.

Answer (score 0):

In open Office Calc u can simply go to: Insert > Sheet (or.. Sheet from file if u want to import one from another file) and u can set it active by using the sheet Arrows at the bottom of the screen to the left.

btw: the new sheet will be added BEFORE Sheet1 not after Sheet3 and u can drag the sheets to re-arrange them the way u need.

sorry didnt read the topic very well (:

Comment: -1 For not even reading the question. It's about opening a new workbook with just one sheet, not adding a new worksheet to a current one.